# ffmpeg modify audio length/size ( stretch or shrink)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am developing a web app, where people can record videos. I have been able to send chunks of audio n video to server successfully, where I am trying to combine them and return as single proper file.

my problem is if the recording is for one hour, after merging the chunks

video length : 1:00:00 , audio length : 00:59:30,

now, this is not a issue of audio not getting recorded( I have checked that), the problem is, somehow, when i merge the chunks of audio, it shrinks,

> I find that it is progressive sync issue where it gets worse and worse as time increases.

I have searched the net for the solution, most places say `async`, I have tried using it, but to no avail, is the below usage correct?

`ffmpeg  -i audio.wav -async 1 -i video.webm -y -strict -2 v.mp4`

(v.mp4 is the final file that I provide to the users.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found a solution(or a temp fix, depends of how you look at it),

it involves combination of `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` ... i have done audio streching( ratio<1)

```
ffprobe -i  a.mp3  -show_entries  format=duration  -v quiet  -print_format json
ffprobe -i  v.mp4  -show_entries  format=duration  -v quiet  -print_format json
ffmpeg  -i a.mp3 -filter:a atempo="0.9194791304347826" aSync.mp3   // audio is being stretched. 
ffmpeg  -i aSync.mp3 -i v.mp4 final.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mido's great answer, I made a Windows batch file that does this in one step.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
GOTO:main

:usage
ECHO USAGE:
ECHO  %~nx0 audio_file video_file
GOTO :end


:main
SET "BAT_NAME=%~nx0"
SET "A0_FILE=%1"
SET "V_FILE=%2"

IF "%A0_FILE%"=="" GOTO :usage
IF "%V_FILE%"=="" GOTO :usage

SET "A1_FILE=%~n1.synced%~x1"
SET "A1_FILE_FULLY_QUALIFIED=%~d1%~p1%~n1.synced%~x1"

REM ffprobe report of video length to temporary file
ffprobe -i "%V_FILE%" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -print_format compact=p=0:nk=1 > _dura.txt
REM there is a newline at the end of the report file which I do not want
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO @ECHO|SET /p="%%x" >> _dura_tr.txt
REM replace the untrimmed file with the good one
MOVE /Y _dura_tr.txt _dura.txt >nul
REM finally I can put the duration into a variable
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO SET V_DURATION=%%x
REM delete the temporary file
DEL _dura.txt
REM echo the result
ECHO Video length: %V_DURATION%

ffprobe -i "%A0_FILE%" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -print_format compact=p=0:nk=1 > _dura.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO @ECHO|SET /p="%%x" >> _dura_tr.txt
MOVE /Y _dura_tr.txt _dura.txt >nul
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO SET A0_DURATION=%%x
DEL _dura.txt
ECHO Audio length: %A0_DURATION%

REM I need powershell to be able to get the division of two floats into a variable
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN ('powershell -Command %A0_DURATION%/%V_DURATION%') DO SET A_TEMPO=%%x
REM replace comma with dot if present because of locale
SET A_TEMPO=%A_TEMPO:,=.%
REM echo the result
ECHO Calculated audio tempo: %A_TEMPO%

ECHO Creating "%A1_FILE%"
REM finally with the known tempo I can make the synced audio file
ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -y -i "%A0_FILE%" -filter:a atempo="%A_TEMPO%" "%A1_FILE_FULLY_QUALIFIED%"
ECHO Done.

ffprobe -i "%A1_FILE%" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -print_format compact=p=0:nk=1 > _dura.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO @ECHO|SET /p="%%x" >> _dura_tr.txt
MOVE /Y _dura_tr.txt _dura.txt >nul
FOR /F "delims=" %%x IN (_dura.txt) DO SET A1_DURATION=%%x
ECHO New audio length: %A1_DURATION%
DEL _dura.txt

GOTO :end

:end
ENDLOCAL
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Szieberth\Videos>syncaudio2video.bat a.wav v.mp4
Video length: 1855.007000
Audio length: 1859.328000
Calculated audio tempo: 1.00232937126383
Creating "a.synced.wav"
Done.
New audio length: 1855.010938
```